# ng-csv: how to add csv-header dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv

I need to create `csv-header` dynamically from the result of the API call, so I did below but `csv-header` always comes empty because `ng-csv` already started building

Currently, I have below code:

**HTML**

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary"
                  ng-csv="$ctrl.submit()"
                  filename="data.csv"
                  csv-header="$ctrl.headers">\
```

JS

```
this.submit = () => {
        return service.find().then(results => {
          let response = srvice.getCsvFileData(results);
          this.headers = response.headers;

          return response.data;
        })
      };
```

But it always export file without headers.

Also, I don't want to repeat like below:

```
this.getHeaders= () => {
            return service.find().then(results => {
              let response = srvice.getCsvFileData(results);
              return response.headers;
            })
          };
```

Comment: With this commit https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv/pull/219/files
csv-header could be an expression, a value or a promise.

Comment: Hi Deamon, were you able to find a solution for this? 
Could you possibly share?